# How to send (put) "Array" values into XMLHttpRequest Object Ajax Request?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, xmlhttprequest

We can send (put) single values to send into XMLHttpRequest with Ajax. But how to send "Array" element's values?

**EXAMPLE#1 (Ok!)**
For this simple value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="hello" />
```

We can simply put the value into XMLHttpRequest object like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?param="+document.getElementById("param").value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Above method is simple and ok.
But how about to send (put) "Array" values?

**EXAMPLE#2 * (Problem with Array Values)**

```
<input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="hello" />
<input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="world" />
...
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?params="+document.getElementById("param").value,true);
```

Note: Server side will be with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference (except for a slight change in name). They are just elements with `[]` in the name attribute as far as HTML, JavaScript and HTTP are concerned. Only PHP is picky about naming conventions for form controls (every other server side language I've encountered deals with expectations of single or multiple values on the server alone, instead of both the server and the client)

The problem is that your initial approach isn't going to work (except in old IE and IE in quirks mode). `getElementById` gets an element by its **ID** and your elements only have names.

You can either give the elements IDs or use `getElementsByName('param[]')` and loop.

Note that you also need to use `encodeURIComponent` on the data to make it safe for sticking in a URL.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('param[]');
var query = [];
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    query.push( encodeURIComponent(input.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value) );
}
var url = "ajax.php?" + query.join('&');
```

Comment: I can't get what you give. Also, what is `var input = inputs[1;` means ? With single bracket `[1` ?

Comment: Seems your script has error inside `for` loop. Coz i can't even `alert("aaaa");` after the loop.

Comment: [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/j4qnc/). It has been a long time since I manually constructed a query string.

Comment: Ya its now send with the values `?param[]=one&param[]=two&param[]=three`. But can't catch from the php. How should i ?

Comment: Woah! Thats so great!! I couldn't get before because `POST` method didn't work and now its ok with `GET` method. So great!! :)